# Realm write transaction pattern

Tags: swift, realm

Two main problems. The [Realm Swift Docs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#writes) don't give very verbose examples of write transactions. Their examples force the try catch pattern and they just say "Don't do this in production". First, I'm looking for a really good pattern to encapsulate a write transaction. Here is what I currently do:

```
// Define your models like regular Swift classes
public class Dog: Object {
    @objc public private(set) dynamic var name: String?
    public let age = RealmOptional<Int>()
    public private(set) var owner: Person?
}

//MARK: Extension that has functions to update properties
extension Dog {
    public func updateName(_ name: String?) throws {
        do{
            let realm = try Realm()
            let inWrite = realm.isInWriteTransaction
            if !inWrite {
                realm.beginWrite()
            }
            self.name = name
            if !inWrite {
                try realm.commitWrite()
            }
        }catch{
            throw error
        }
    }
}
```

This pattern mirrors the try catch pattern that Realm uses and guards agains the realm currently being in a write transaction. Thoughts on this pattern?

My second problem comes from having to write a function like this for every property I want to change. Is their a more efficient way to do this? Keeping in mind Realm becomes more efficient if changes are grouped inside a single write transaction?

NOTE: The need for this abstraction comes from the fact that I usually put Realm inside a reusable library like a cocoapod. A lot of transaction code living in `UIViewController`'s gets really messy.

Comment: What're you trying to achieve by having an `updateName` method like that rather than having the caller simply do `dog.name = newName` while within a write transaction?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve a layer of abstraction away from a UI. If I wanted to have Realm objects inside a framework or something. This way all the boilerplate realm code does not have to live in some `UIViewController` which already gets large.